# How do I keep my session when I reboot in OS X?

Tags: macos, reboot

When I reboot my machine, I'd like it to reopen all my programs and windows, and put them back in the same place, after restarting. how do I do this?

(I'm on 10.6, and use spaces)

Comment: Please let ReLaunch developer know you'd like spaces support. Might help get it implemented...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ReLaunch](http://wiredupandfiredup.co.uk/Relaunch/) does what you want. Also see [a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/184394/remember-desktop-state-after-reboot) on SuperUser.

The only major limitation of Relaunch is it does not (yet) support Spaces (virtual desktops).

Answer (score 1):

You can start as many application at startup by adding them to your Account Prefs :

[image]

For the windows... I don't think there is an easy way to do it. But if it's some documents, you can added them the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I started an Applescript to start up the applications that make the core of my day, though I need to add in more functionality like opening specific URLs and folders (though it wouldn't be hard, I just haven't had the time).

```
tell application "Firefox"
    activate
end tell

tell application "Versions"
    activate
end tell

tell application "NetNewsWire"
    activate
end tell
```

I saved it as an application, named it "AM" and it sits on the far left of my Dock. I come into my office in morning, wake up my Mac, and click the icon.

Comment: You can use Login Items in the Accounts section of System Preferences to do this.

Comment: Yes, but I don't shut down my Mac except for a weekly reboot on Monday mornings.